# QT sending post array, how to recieve it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, qt, post

Hi all so here is a code I want to receive data in PHP.

so I have this in QT:

```
 QUrl params;
    params.addQueryItem("action","Dodaj_korisnika");
    params.addQueryItem("ime","qt");
    params.addQueryItem("prezime","QT");
    params.addQueryItem("broj","998873");
    params.addQueryItem("adresa","kkakka");

        QByteArray data;
        data.append(params.toString());
        data.remove(0,1);

        QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

How to write PHP to retireve array.
I have tried this:

```
$_FIELD=array( 
"action" => $_POST{action}, 
"ime" => $_POST{ime}, 
"prezime" => $_POST{prezime}, 
"broj" => $_POST{broj}, 
"adresa" => $_POST{adresa}
```

its not working 
and this:
$_POST `array($_POST['action'],$_POST['ime'],$_POST['prezime'],$_POST['broj'],$_POST['adresa'];`
still not working..any idea what is right way to get post data..
    );

Comment: Does your QT code do what it should? Did you check if the `replyFinished` slot gets called? If yes, also check if the `error` property of the given QNetworkReply is `QNetworkReply::NoError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is like any other array in PHP and can be accessed like this:

```
echo $_POST['action']; // echos the value for the key "action"
```

To see whats in there you can use:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: so in php I have variable like $_POST['action] then $_POST['ime']; I dont need extra code for reading? as I send only as array? okay I'll try

Answer (score -2):

Your code has syntax errors . It must be like this :

```
$field = array(
     "action"=>$_POST["action"],
     "ime"=>$_POST["ime"],
     "prezime"=>$_POST["prezime"],
     "broj"=>$_POST["broj"],
     "adresa"=>$_POST["adresa"],
);
```

Comment: Highlighter tells me this won't compile

Comment: Plus you would better suggested just `$field = $_POST;`. Less chances to make a mistake in the answer.

Comment: @Eray No, it still won't. have you tested it?

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense at all. What's the gain in this? Creating another array with the POST parameters is redundant, except you like to type `$field['action']` instead of `$_POST['action']`. Also associative arrays should be written like this: `array( 'key' => 'value' );`

Comment: @TimWolla , @bummzack , he tried this `$_FIELD=array( 
"action" => $_POST{action}, 
"ime" => $_POST{ime}, 
"prezime" => $_POST{prezime}, 
"broj" => $_POST{broj}, 
"adresa" => $_POST{adresa} ` and as you can see, there are syntax errors (because he said this is a PHP array) . Just i fixed it. I don't know QT code .

Comment: @Eray, It won't even compile! PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in php shell code on line 2

Comment: @TimWolla , haha because i forgot . Because i'm trying to be hurry :D Use `=>` instead of `=`

Comment: You really should not answer when you are in hurry. SO is about making great answers not bad answers…